# How to fix element's width and border in CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

[image]

The picture speaks for itself - left element has the required border style at different browser window widths, right element at the same row has squared border at browser's window width ~1751px, while the bottom element (which is .rightcolumn) is fully stretched and the top-right corner is round instead of the bottom two rounded. Tried almost all combinations of box models without a result ...

Here's the `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='content'>
            <div id='sites'>
                <div id="leftcolumn" class='column leftcolumn'></div>
        <div id="middlecolumn" class='column middlecolumn'></div>
        <div id="rightcolumn" class='column rightcolumn'></div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the `style.css` code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* the following media queries change the column corners based on the current width of the browser window */
@media (max-width: 1392px) {
  .middlecolumn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1.5em !important;
  }

  .rightcolumn {
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5em !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5em !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 702px) {
  .leftcolumn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1.5em !important;
  }

  .middlecolumn {
    border-top-right-radius: 0em !important;
  }
}

html {
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("space.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%; /* fix for android devices */
  /* overflow: hidden; */ /* fix for android devices, currently disabled for desktops */
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#sites {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* row wrap set elements to follow each other as in row and to wrap when the browser is resized */
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
  box-orient: vertical;
  box-align: center;
  box-pack: center;
  box-lines: multiple;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 0.1em;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
}

/* The following three classes set the column borders when the browser window is min 1392px wide */
.leftcolumn {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5em;
}

.middlecolumn {
  /* no rounded corners */
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.rightcolumn {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5em;
}
```

And this is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/539to64f/1/ , where 3rd column has bottom-border-radius enabled while at the same row with the first two columns. Probably something about how jsfiddle handles the output window but don't know for sure ...

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: O-o ... That's the code and the visual problem is still here. I'm on 1920x1080 resolution and changing slowly the browser's window horizontal width activates it

Comment: Added browser's window width in pixels where the problem occurs

Comment: Running updated code in jsfiddle.net still doesn't reproduce the problem. Try getting it to show there?

Comment: This is rly weird, added and jsfiddle

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y5w260mL/) ?

Comment: Yes, but on specific width range. The whole thing should maintain round corners at top and bottom with 1 or 2 column width, at 3 in a row only top left and right corners should be rounded